# Local login ASP.Net web API with windows account administrators

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm new to using MVC and Web API, and I need to create an API with the individual user accounts security so that external users can register and login.

But then I want internal administrators within the company to be able to manage the API user accounts. These admins are already logged on to their local machines with windows AD accounts, and I don't want them to have to log on again to the API.

So far the only way I've found to do this is to have the API, and then a separate MVC site for the internal admins that use windows account logins.

It seems a bit messy / awkward though, is there a better way of doing this? Am I looking at it completely the wrong way?

Comment: check this question  and response . Same answer holds good for this scenario as well.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734237/different-authentication-mode-for-different-areas

Comment: Thanks @sameer, are there benefits to creating a child application over a separate application?

Comment: Would lean towards Separate Application considering  above mentioned scenario which will provide following benefits each application can evolve independently, Admin module is more of API Management Functionality and can be a separate application in itself .

Comment: Fab, thanks for you help @sameer :)